# sencha touch :: how to pass index-Id from list into XTemplate function

Tags: list, templates, sencha-touch, arguments

I want to create a dynamically variating list with XTemplates. unfort. you can't pass the index-id though a function within an if-construct like

```
var newItemTpl = '<div class="list_websites_item"><div class="' + cmp.id + '">' + orgItemTpl + '</div>' + '<div class="iconset">' + 
'<tpl if="Ext.getCmp(\'' + cmp.id + '\').plugins[0].isPendingItem({[xindex-1]})">'+
    '<p>IS PENDING</p>'+
  '</tpl>' +
'</div></div>';
```

when I call isPendingItem({[xindex-1]}) with argument I get the error

```
SyntaxError: Parse error
```

So how could I pass arguments here?

thnx!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the in-built template variables (xindex, xcount, values etc) directly within an if tag so if you change your code to remove the enclosing '{[]}' then it should work:

```
var newItemTpl = '<div class="list_websites_item"><div class="' + cmp.id + '">' + 

orgItemTpl + '</div>' + '<div class="iconset">' + 
'<tpl if="Ext.getCmp(\'' + cmp.id + '\').plugins[0].isPendingItem(xindex-1)">'+
    '<p>IS PENDING</p>'+
  '</tpl>' +
'</div></div>';
```

Comment: didn't test it because I found a good workaround in my case. but your solution seems to be the right way. so thanx!